# Making a bootable cd/dvd using PowerISO

Tags: windows-7, bootable-media

I'm stuck with a problem, initially I have an empty DVD.
I'm using windows 7
I'm using PowerISO for burning

And I'm doing the following:

1. open the corresponding OS ISO-file with PowerISO
2. extract it to DVD

everything looks fine.

Then I restarted my system to boot with this DVD (wind8). I use my boot manager to select the DVD but it still boots with the previously existing windows7 instead of installing win8 from the DVD.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Extracting sounds wrong. ISO images are meant to be burned with a program supporting this, like ImgBurn. You don’t extract them and you also don’t burn a DVD where the ISO file appears as a file on the DVD.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like OS DVD you have created using ISO file is not bootable.  In this case please make sure that you have followed the below mentioned article for burning the ISO file into a bootable disc.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

If you have folllowed the same , then verify the below article for further troubleshooting:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2793441

If this is not the case, you can narrow down to root cause by trying an alternate bootable DVD on this machine or trying to boot this DVD on another machine.

Comment: ya U tried best in answering to my question...one thing u told that the iso file i have created using iso file is not bootable.if so i just opened up my dvd there after i clicked on set up...and its upgraded to the os (win7).If the error is really with bootable iso this can't be happen ...what could be the problem.???